# date picker text field and icon coming out of div bootstrap panel

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap panel in which I am trying to place a date icon with input field in it but the input field coming out of div panel.I tried to reduce the width of input field but it didn't work.

Here is the below image what i have tried

[image]

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <span class="text-left">
              Default | Expires on 2018/09/10
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-pause"></i> |
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> |
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> |
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                               name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
                              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>                        
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>            
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I recommend you post the HTML output that you get in the browser instead of stuff that contains Angular code.

Comment: @WebDevBooster the Html code also showing same output can u help me with the issue?

Comment: Read his page: [mcve]